# DevExpress GridControl seletcted rows belong to Parent View or Child View in Master-Details mode

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm using `Dev-express GridControl` in my Win-forms project.

How can I detect that selected rows belongs to a Parent View or a Child View in Master-Details mode?

Comment: In which event? You can handle events for both views separatly.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič : I'm implementing a feature to user can move up and down selected rows by clicking a special buttons, so when I handle `upButton_Clicked` or `downButton_Clicked` I want to know which rows I should move.

Comment: Please, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GridView's [IsMasterRow](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.IsMasterRow(System.Int32)) method or the GridView's [IsDetailRowIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.IsDetailRowIndex(System.Int32-DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView)) method to determine if a row handle belongs to a master or child view.

Answer (score 0):

To get a GridView instance in which a user just selected a row, use the [GridControl.FocusedView](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.FocusedView) property.